# Conditional Formatting Excel

Tags: macos, excel, excel-formula

I need to highlight row value based on value of two cells.
I need the formula to work for entire worksheet.

for eg : if value of B2 > 0 and value of P2 = "NOT OK" then highlight the row with pink color.

But when i add the formula on mac excel 2011 like AND($B2>0,$P2="NOT OK")..its not working.

Comment: What does "its not working" mean?

Comment: did you put `=` at the beginning of the formula? is `,` your list separator and not `;`? Is B2 actually a positive number and P2 actually has exact value of "NOT OK"? Is there a format set in the conditional formatting? Is it applied to the whole area you want to check and not only to some cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That formula

```
AND($B2>0,$P2="NOT OK")
```

should work. When you create it, make sure that you highlight the whole area, starting from the first applicable cell in row 2, to the bottom-right of the area. The formula is applied relative to the *currently active row*.

Also ensure that the cell value is exactly "NOT OK"; that is, without any leading or trailing spaces.